# Perl - Requires explicit package name

Tags: perl

I have googled around and looked online and I understand a few criteria would need to be met in order to get this function to work, however, I don't understand why it's able to work in the first place.

Context:
I have a Perl script that I want to integrate into a Perl module. The situation is that I'm new to the language and I'm a bit unsure the difference and I don't understand why this error is coming up in the first place.

The Perl module is this:
https://github.com/slic3r/Slic3r/blob/master/lib/Slic3r/Print/SupportMaterial.pm

I thought I could just add the script into the module and be done, but unfortunately, that is not the case due to the error message. Now to what I know so far as someone new to Perl, you need to declare them "my ..." or remove use strict. I am somewhat interested in the latter since the script is working correctly. Does anyone have any help or tips?

Comment: You already know the recommended solution – to declare the offending variables with `my`. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: How do I do them for some of them though? I'm a bit unsure. For eample, the sub branch method has $rho, $theta, $phi in the for loop. Can I declare them as my in those brackets?

Comment: Removing `use strict;` should not be considered an option.

Comment: You have oodles on undeclared variables, which is why you're getting the error message. Declare them!

Comment: You should wrap that top-level code in curlies (`{ ... }`) so that you can properly scope variables to that code.

Comment: @user9903818 *"Can I declare them as my in those brackets?"* Yes, just put `my` in front: `my ($rho, $theta, $phi) = cartesian_to_spherical(...)`

Comment: `my ($rho, $theta, $phi)` is equivalent to `(my $rho, my $theta, my $phi)`

Answer (score 2):

> Now to what I know so far as someone new to Perl, you need to declare them "my ..." or remove use strict. I am somewhat interested in the latter since the script is working correctly. Does anyone have any help or tips?

Declaring the variables with `my` is the right approach. `use strict` does an number of things - forcing variable declaration is only one of them.

No serious Perl programmer would consider writing code without `use strict` and `use warnings`. Removing them is a bad idea.

Comment: Not to mention, they're not equivalent. `my` creates local variables. If you remove `use strict;`, all you get is (implicit) globals. You still need `my` to declare local variables, strict or not.